# Converting POPO Object in Obj-C object

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, reflection

I have to ask you a question! I'm studying some cases to create a RESTFul WS for an App. After some days, I decided to start developing it in PHP. I'm doing a POPO Object using also the Abstract **JsonSerializable** class. Well, the server side is done!!
Now I want to automate the iOS side building iOS classes conform to the POPO Object. Then, when iOS receive the data from the connection, I want to reflect the data to find the correct class. I think about a process like this:

**NSData -> NSDictionary -> Reflection -> POPO iOS Class**

Well, the **Reflection** step is still on working because I really don't want to analyze all the NSDictionary to find the correct POPO. I will not do things such as below...

```
if ([dictionary.firstObject isKindOfClass: [POPObject class]])
{
    POPObject *popo = [[POPObject alloc] initWithObj: dictionary.firstObject];
    return popo;
}
```

I'm not doing this because some POPOObject will contain NSArray property that will contain other POPObjects! So, maybe is better if I elaborate something of recursive...
I will explain it well. Think at a JSON like this:

```
{
  "firstFatherObj": {
    "firstObject": true,
    "secondObject": {
      "firstProperty" : true,
      "secondProperty": "Prop"
    }
  },
  "http-status": 200
}
```

It is a sample example, but there will be some second/third/fourth/etc... level of subclasses and it will be more expensive and really heavy. Any ideas? Thanks!

### ADDING

I'm thinking about some Abstract ResponseObject that they will group more POPObject in iOS. So, when I do a call to the server, I know something about the response I will wait for. So I'm going to create this Abstract and I'm going to delegate it the parsing stuff to its related POPObject. 
An example: I'm going to ask to the server some information about the logged user. I haven't to check for all the POPObject (that surely they are not all about *USER*), but I instantiate the **ResponseUser** object that will parse the JSON and it will understand which is the suitable class (ex: userPosts, userPreferences and others..). 
What do you think about it?

Comment: How much will your iOS app know about the kinds of objects it can receive? Are you trying to build something so generic that the server can return any kind of object and the client just handles it? Are you trying to create strongly typed objects on the client side, or loose dictionaries that can contain whatever the server decides to send? It's not clear what degree of coupling you are willing to accept.

Comment: Hi @MikeTaverne. My iOS app will know all about the objects because, once the app receive the object, it's going to modify it and it's going to send it to the server. So server and client have to be **synchronized**. I thought about a ResponseObject that will be an Abstract for all the POPObject, and I will manipulate it to the particular class...